# PHP with DB backed-end application to complete windows EXE possible or not?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a php application backed-end with SQLite and I would like to convert whole application to exe file so the end user can just click it and run on windows.
User should be able to save, update and add new data into database without any web server or browser things.
Is it possible?

I found out that we can use PHP-GTK for UI.

exeoutput.com supports with database engines according to it's website. Anyone have tried it out?
If I'm missing something, pls share with me.

Thanks all in advance and happy new year!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'd be able to do this natively, not as an exe on windows.

I've never tried exeoutput.com, so can't comment on that however...

There are some 3rd party compilers for php which may let you convert your code into an exe file and run it under windows, [phc](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) being one example, and [roadsend](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler) providing another. I've not tried these, so I can't really comment on how well they work.

Alternatively, you could write some native windows code to launch your php app, but this might be a bit tricky.

One more option (again, I've not tried this) is [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) which translates PHP into C++ code, so if you're prepared to experiment, this might give you a good option.